# .htacces redirection for specific files

Tags: .htaccess

i know that there are a lot of questions about  .htaccess, but i am not able to find the solution.

I have an index.php on a folder on my domain.

```
mydomain.com/folder/index.php
```

This index.php list 3 urls that i do not want the people to see, i only want them to be redirected to the first one.
I cannot modify the index.php file, i need to redirect the trafic using htaccess, this way:

I need to redirect everything that go to

```
mydomain.com/folder/
www.mydomain.com/folder/
mydomain.com/folder/index.php
www.mydomain.com/folder/index.php
```

and send them into this url

```
www.mydomain.com/folder/text
```

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: ¿Is `/folder` in the mapped URL the same `/folder` in the incoming URLs? If not, ¿which folders should be redirected and what's the name of the folder in the mapped URL?

Comment: Yes, /folder is always the same for all four options and the same for the redirected one.